# Problema ao conectar no MySQL pelo Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013

Estou tentando realizar a conexão pelo Visual Studio, quando vou configurar pelo 'Data Source Configuration Wizard' está apresentando um erro: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo que eu já importei e referenciei as .dll(s) do MySQL meu projeto. Porém, continua a apresentar esse erro.

Comment: Paulo, já tentou instalar o [MySQL for Visual Studio](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/)?